Extending a holomorphic function on $\Omega\backslash\mathbb R$ to a holomorphic function on $\Omega$
In my search for a solution to this question, I got stuck at a point while performing the subdivision as suggested in the comments: It's true that the size of the triangles (the perimeter, to be more accurate) goes to zero and that the integral around any small triangle is zero, but we are interested in the integral around the large triangle. That integral is the sum of these small integrals. If we perform the subdivision, we see that the perimeter of the $n$-th triangle is $\frac{P}{n}$ (where P is the perimeter of the original large triangle) while the number of triangles that have a side on the real axis at the n-th iteration is $n$. This means the total integral, which is the sum of these smaller integrals, is as follows:
$$\int_{\partial T}f(z) \, \mathrm dz=\sum_{i=1}^n\int_{\partial T_i}f(z) \, \mathrm dz \leq PM$$
where $M$ is the maximum value of the function on the large triangle $T$, and $T_i$ are the small triangles touching the real axis. This doesn't lead to the integral around the large triangle being zero. This leads me to the bound, which can already be obtained without subdivision. Does anyone know how can I improve on this subdivision scheme?
I also saw this question by the same person, and the answer given by someone there is clear. I was just wondering if anyone knew if it is possible to prove it using some subdivision.
